# Sorting an array in order to move an element from one place to another, while keeping `order` field the same

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort an array based on its `order` field, and I'm having a bit of trouble.

Suppose I have the following array,

```
const array = [
  {order: 3, name: 'A'},
  {order: 10, name: 'B'},
  {order: 11, name: 'C'},
  {order: 23, name: 'D'},
  {order: 47, name: 'E'},
  {order: 91, name: 'F'},
];
```

Notice how the `order` field of each consequent object isn't larger by 1 than the previous. This is ok -- the only thing that matters, is that the array is in ascending order.

Now, suppose I try to move,

```
{order: 47, name: 'E'}
```

to the second place of the array (`array[1]`), while preserving all `order` values.

The new array would look like,

```
[
  {order: 3, name: 'A'},
  {order: 47, name: 'E'},
  {order: 11, name: 'C'},
  {order: 23, name: 'D'},
  {order: 10, name: 'B'},
  {order: 91, name: 'F'},
];
```

I'm trying to sort this new array in such a way, that the output should be:

```
[
  {order: 3, name: 'A'},
  {order: 10, name: 'E'},
  {order: 11, name: 'B'},
  {order: 23, name: 'C'},
  {order: 47, name: 'D'},
  {order: 91, name: 'F'},
];
```

How can I achieve this?

I've tried different combinations of something like the below to no avail,

```
const compare = (a, b) => {
  if (a.order < b.order) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a.order > b.order) {
      const temp = a.id;
      a.order = b.order;
      b.order = temp;

      return 1;
    }

  return 0; 
}

array.sort(compare);
```

Having a bit of a brainfart here. What am I doing wrong? I've also tried playing around with `splice` to pull the element out its original place and place it in its new intended position, but I was running into issues with the ordering of the `order` field.

Comment: Uh, don't change `order` *while sorting*. You are very unlikely to get the result you want. In fact, it's probably best if you don't change any object while sorting regardless of what the sorting criteria is.

Comment: Why are `order` and `name` bound together in the same array to begin with? What you seem to want is to treat them completely separate from another.

Comment: Do you need to have `order: 10` for `E` after moving it? As in, do you need to preserve the `order`s or is it OK to just find any value within the gap?

Comment: I'm using [react-beautiful-dnd](https://codesandbox.io/embed/k260nyxq9v?codemirror=1) and I'm trying to save the requested sort order in my database. Records are in a certain order, where `order` is unique. I'm trying to change that order.

Comment: @VLAZ I need to preserve `order`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that mutating the array during the sort is necessarily a good idea. You could extract your orders in an array and `shift` to get the next order? You could also just do a swap programmatically.

```js
const orders = [
  {order: 3, name: 'A'},
  {order: 47, name: 'E'},
  {order: 11, name: 'C'},
  {order: 23, name: 'D'},
  {order: 10, name: 'B'},
  {order: 91, name: 'F'},
];

function sortOrders() {
  const allOrders = orders.map(({order}) => order);
  allOrders.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  return orders.map((order) => {
    order.order = allOrders.shift();
    return order;
  });
}

function swap(idx1, idx2) {
  const ordersClone = orders.slice(0);
  const tempOrder = orders[idx1].order;
  ordersClone[idx2] = orders[idx1];
  ordersClone[idx2].order = orders[idx2].order;
  
  ordersClone[idx1] = orders[idx2];
  ordersClone[idx1].order = tempOrder;
  return ordersClone
}

console.log(sortOrders(orders));
console.log(swap(1, 4));
```

This will effectively keep the order of the `name` attribute and will rename all the `order` attributes based on a sorted array of `order` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Do not attempt to modify the array while sorting. Instead:

1. Use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to move the item to a new position
2. Adjust the `order` parameter of the sub-section of the array where the item was moved:

```js
function move(arr, fromIndex, toIndex) {
  //move the item
  const [itemToMove] = arr.splice(fromIndex, 1); //take next item from the iterator
  arr.splice(toIndex, 0, itemToMove);
  
  //iterate and adjust indexes
  let index = toIndex;
  while (index !== fromIndex) {
    let nextIndex = fromIndex < toIndex
      ? index - 1  //descending
      : index + 1; //ascending
    
    const current = arr[index];
    const next = arr[nextIndex];
    
    //swap the order parameters
    [current.order, next.order] = [next.order, current.order];
    
    //go to the next item
    index = nextIndex;
  }
  
  return arr;
}

const array = [
  {order: 3, name: 'A'},
  {order: 10, name: 'B'},
  {order: 11, name: 'C'},
  {order: 23, name: 'D'},
  {order: 47, name: 'E'},
  {order: 91, name: 'F'},
];


console.log( move(array, 4, 1) );
```

Or here is an alternative where first a snapshot of the current `order`s is taken and then after the swap it's restored to the affected subsection of the array:

```js
function move(arr, fromIndex, toIndex) {
  const start = Math.min(fromIndex, toIndex);
  const end   = Math.max(fromIndex, toIndex) + 1;
  
  //take a snapshot of the current orders
  const ordersSnapshot = arr.slice(start, end+1)
    .map(({order}) => order);
  const ordersIterator = ordersSnapshot.values();
  
  //move the item
  const [itemToMove] = arr.splice(fromIndex, 1);
  arr.splice(toIndex, 0, itemToMove);
  
  //restore the orders
  for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
    [arr[i].order] = ordersIterator;
  }
    
  return arr;
}

const array = [
  {order: 3, name: 'A'},
  {order: 10, name: 'B'},
  {order: 11, name: 'C'},
  {order: 23, name: 'D'},
  {order: 47, name: 'E'},
  {order: 91, name: 'F'},
];


console.log( move(array, 4, 1) );
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const arr = [{
    order: 3,
    name: 'A'
  },
  {
    order: 47,
    name: 'E'
  },
  {
    order: 11,
    name: 'C'
  },
  {
    order: 23,
    name: 'D'
  },
  {
    order: 10,
    name: 'B'
  },
  {
    order: 91,
    name: 'F'
  },
];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.order - b.order;
});

console.log(arr)
```

You can sort the array of objects using one of their properties.

Comment: I think the question is not to sort by order, but to keep the current order with their name, but to update the `order` property. (i.e. A, E, C is not the correct order)